# How to fix the no 'setup' error in cogs in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am getting an error :-  `Extension 'cogs.Funny' has no 'setup' function.` but I have added the `setup` function so how do I fix it?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

class Funny(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def rps(self,ctx):
        e = discord.Embed(Title = "Rps",description = "Please react with  for rock,  for paper and ✂ for scissors",color = discord.Colour.blue())
        m = await ctx.send(embed = e)
        z = ['rock','scissors','paper']
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ['','','✂']
    
        await m.add_reaction('')
        await m.add_reaction('')
        await m.add_reaction('✂')

        try:
            reaction, user = await self.client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
                a = random.choice(z)
                if a == 'rock':
                    new = discord.Embed(title = "Result",description = f"The bot chose {a} and u chose rock so its a tie",color = discord.Colour.purple())
                    await m.edit(embed = new)
                elif a == 'scissors':
                    new = discord.Embed(title = "Result",description = f"The bot chose {a} and u chose rock so You Won!!",color = discord.Colour.green())
                    await m.edit(embed = new)
                else:
                    new = discord.Embed(title = "Result",description = f"The bot chose {a} and u chose rock so You lost :(",color = discord.Colour.red())
                    await m.edit(embed = new)
                
            if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
                a = random.choice(z)
                if a == 'paper':
                    new = discord.Embed(title = "Result",description = f"The bot chose {a} and u chose paper so its a tie",color = discord.Colour.purple())
                    await m.edit(embed = new)
                elif a == 'rock':
                    new = discord.Embed(title ="Result",description =  f"The bot chose {a} and u chose paper so You Won!!",color = discord.Colour.green())
                    await m.edit(embed = new)
                else:
                    new = discord.Embed(title ="Result",description =  f"The bot chose {a} and u chose paper so You lost :(",color = discord.Colour.red())
                    await m.edit(embed = new)
            if str(reaction.emoji) == '✂':
                a = random.choice(z)
                if a == 'scissors':
                    new = discord.Embed(title = "Result",description = f"The bot chose {a} and u chose scissors so its a tie",color = discord.Colour.purple())
                    await m.edit(embed = new)
                
                elif a == 'paper':
                    new = discord.Embed(title ="Result",description = f"The bot chose {a} and u chose scissors so You Won!!",color = discord.Colour.green())
                    await m.edit(embed = new)
                else:
                    new = discord.Embed(title ="Result",description = f"The bot chose {a} and u chose scissors so You lost :(",color = discord.Colour.red())
                    await m.edit(embed = new)
    
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Funny(client))
    print("fun is loaded")
```

Edit:- I forgot to tell how  it loads it:-

```
extensions = [
            'cogs.Funny'
]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for extension in extensions:
        try:
            client.load_extension(extension)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"error while loading {extension}",file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. The extension is loaded without any errors at all.

Comment: Is your file named `Funny.py`?

Comment: yeah its name is `Funny.py` and its in the `cogs` folder

Comment: Well the code works like a charm to me.

Comment: oh never mind i tried debugging it and it works now, sorry was my bad i should have done that earlier